# How can i get current fee from monero-wallet-rpc

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, transaction-fees

I wanna make transactions during monero-wallet-rpc.
When I wanna send some amount I wanna know the fee's before Im transfering the funds to other wallet.

How can i get the fee's regarding a trasaction from monero-wallet-rpc API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fee depends (in part) on the exact size of your transaction, and your transaction size depends (in part) on how many outputs you are spending. Therefore to determine the fee, you first need to construct the transaction to determine its size. You can do this using the `transfer` method with `do_not_relay` set to `true`.

If you are happy with the fee, you can then submit the transaction to the network using the `relay_tx` method.

Comment: ill try it out now